# Clear icon inside input text box angular way

Tags: angularjs

I have been trying to create a clear icon inside text box.

My code snippet will do below things:

1. initially clear icon is hidden
2. when we type anything in text box, if the text box is in focus and the text box has some value in it then the clear icon will be displayed.
3. If anyone click on clear icon, it will clear the corresponding text box content.

**In simple I want to create a replica of clear icon that is displayed in webkit browsers search box.**

When I click on clear icon it will clear the corresponding text box.
But that doesn't happening

Could anyone figure out what I missed?

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="clearCtrl">
  <div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="userModal" ng-keyup="clearIcon(true)" ng-blur="clearIcon(false)"/>
    <span ng-click="clearInput()" ng-class="clearIconVar?'displayClear':'hideClear'" >x</span>
  </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.displayClear{   
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#38468F;
    position:relative;
    right:21px;
}
.hideClear{
  display:none;
}
```

**angular Javascript**

```
var showApp = angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('clearCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.clearIconVar=false;
  $scope.clearIcon = function(param){
  $scope.clearIconVar=param;
  };
  $scope.hi="hi";
  $scope.clearInput=function(){
    alert("hi");
  };
});
```

**Here is the [jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/cehupucehuvi/1/edit)**

How can one do like this?

I am happy to accept any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all after a while I am able to achieve what I want :)

**So here is the code to achieve what I want**

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="userId" ng-change="clearIconToggle('userId')">
  <span ng-show="userIdClear" ng-click="clearText('userId')">X</span>

  <input type="text" ng-model="passwd" ng-change="clearIconToggle('passwd')">
  <span ng-show="passwdClear" ng-click="clearText('passwd')">X</span>

  <input type="text" ng-model="dob" ng-change="clearIconToggle('dob')">
  <span ng-show="dobClear" ng-click="clearText('dob')">X</span>

</div>
```

JS:

```
var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("MyCtrl",["$scope",function($scope){
  $scope.userIdClear="false";
  $scope.passwdClear="false";
  $scope.dobClear="false";
  $scope.clearIconToggle=function(param){
    
    if($scope[param].length)
      $scope[param+'Clear']=true;
    else
      $scope[param+'Clear']=false;
  };
  $scope.clearText=function(param){
    $scope[param]='';
    $scope.clearIconToggle(param);
  };
  
}]);
```

You can find the working demo [here](http://jsbin.com/jasiyeziyati/2/edit)

---

## Update:

I've created a directive through which you can clear inputs.

Check out the clear-icon directive at [GitHub](https://github.com/gangadharjannu/clear-icon)

Answer (score 6):

this is what i used for my app...

```js
angular.module("sampleApp",[]).controller("sampleCtrl",function($scope){
$scope.inp="hel";
}).directive('clearIcon', ['$compile',
    function($compile) {
 return {
  restrict : 'A',
  link : function(scope, elem, attrs) {
   var model = attrs.ngModel;
   var template = '<span ng-click=\"clearText(\'' + model + '\')\" class="clearIcon"             style="display:none;">x</span>';
   elem.parent().append($compile(template)(scope));
   var clearIconToggle = function(toggleParam) {
    if(elem.val().trim().length)
     elem.next().css("display", "inline");
    else {
     if(elem.next().css("display") == "inline")
      elem.next().css("display", "none");
    }
   };
   var clearText = function(clearParam) {
    elem.val('');
    clearIconToggle(clearParam);
   };
   elem.on("focus", function(event) {
    clearIconToggle(model);
   });
   elem.on("keyup", function(event) {
    clearIconToggle(model);
   });
   elem.next().on("click", function(event) {
    elem.val('');
    elem.next().css("display", "none");
   });
  }
 }; }]);
```

```css
.clearIcon{
color:red;
right:20px;
position:relative;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="sampleApp">
<div ng-controller="sampleCtrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="inp" clear-icon/>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you privied a fiddle please?

Answer (score 0):

This is DOM manipulation that doesn't correspond to any shared "variable", meaning there is no efficient way to do it with angular. It's just unnecessary.

You can do this with jQuery, however as you want to keep it tidy with angularJS, you should put the code inside the directive.

Directive:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function ()
{
    /*
        I'm only adding a link in the return, however you want to be putting the whole element inside a directive to keep it tidy.
        Look into how to use directives.
    */
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs)
        {
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $('#clear-text').click(function()
                {
                    $('#text-box').val("");
                })
            });

        }
    }
});
```

Here's a fiddle of how it would work with just the jQuery (I don't have time to set it up with angular) - http://jsfiddle.net/4oL928pe/

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. I think you've missed something. question Updated see once.

Comment: I don't understand the problem then. You have two problems from what it seems, displaying the icon in webkit browsers and having the functionality to clear an input box. Right?

Comment: Its not the problem. I am trying to simulate the search box like clear icon for every text box, because that search box is browser dependent and we have to use <input type="serach"> so instead of this I am applying that feature to all the inputs like text box, password. Please let me know If you have any doubts?

Comment: No I want one icon for one input box. If I click on icon corresponding text box value will be empty. Once go through the demo so that you might understand what my code snippet does.

Comment: That's what my answer does.

Comment: Hi you've missed two things. Once go through my question "My code snippet will do below things:

initially clear icon is hidden
when we type anything in text box, if the text box is in focus and the text box has some value in it then the clear icon will be displayed.
If anyone click on clear icon, it will clear the corresponding text box content." means Initially clear icon is hidden, whenever you type in text box and if the text box some value then the clear icon will be displayed. Once the textbox loses its focus the clear icon will also be removed. Your answer only did removing the textbox

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="textField" />
    <span ng-show="textField" ng-click="textField = ''">x</span>
</div>
```

Here the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zahorodnyk/7svsyLa8/) demo.